How do you read cookies in Nextjs middleware?
I am using app router. I have set a cookie in one if my api routes on login:
response.cookies.set('session', session.secret, {
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', // Only secure in production
    sameSite: 'strict',
    expires: new Date(session.expire), // Use the correct expiration date
    path: '/',  // Path set to root for entire app
});

I can read the cookie in other api routes like so:
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'; 

const sessionSecretCookie = cookies().get('session');

But when I try to do that in middleware.ts it is undefined.

import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // Access the 'session' cookie
  const sessionSecretCookie = request.cookies.get('session')?.value;

  // You can use the cookie value to add custom logic
  if (!sessionSecretCookie) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }

  // Continue with the request if the session exists
  return NextResponse.next();
}

// Optional: Specify the routes where the middleware should apply
export const config = {
  matcher: ['/dashboard/:path*'], // Apply middleware to specific routes
};


for more details checkout nextjs official middleware documentation.
